# Rails - creating and sending singed cookie in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cookies, minitest

I have a simple rails controller which requires authentication provided via a signed cookie called `auth`.

I can´t figure out how to construct the signed key cookie value from within the test. Normally the `INSERT_SIGNED_COOKIE_HERE` value would be something like `auth=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc...`.

In my `sessions_controller.rb`, which sets the cookie, this value is magically created with `cookies.signed[:auth] = user.id`

My test currently looks similar to following snippet:

```
class RecipesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should create recipe" do
    assert_difference("Recipe.count") do
      post app_recipes_url, params: {
                              recipe: { name: "Spaghetti", instructions: "Here are some instructions", servings: 1 },
                            },
                            headers: {
                              Cookie: INSERT_SIGNED_COOKIE_HERE,
                            }
    end

    assert_redirected_to app_recipe_path(Recipe.last)
  end
end
```

Comment: https://philna.sh/blog/2020/01/15/test-signed-cookies-in-rails/

Comment: The example in the blog post does not work for me (Using rails 6):

`jar = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(request, cookies.to_hash)`
`assert_equal "123", jar.signed["protected"]`


yields this error for the second line:

`NoMethodError: undefined method "key_generator" for nil:NilClass`